# Session and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a site I am building comprised of a main front end at domain.com (its not in production yet - so hopefully specifics not needed). There is a client billing site at client.domain.com

The billing system is encoded - I have very little control over it, but a good API.

I am trying to get some information from that client area via jQuery to display on the front end. The baffling thing is, this was working only two days ago - and has ceased.

The jquery I use to get what I need is simple:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("client/logincheck.php", function(data){
           $('#dynamicsidebar').append(data);
        });
     });
```

Now - the page I call (logincheck.php) is in the client area of the site. In terms of directory structure, it sits under the webroot of the front-end - in the client/ directory, hence I can call it with a relative path.

At the moment, for debugging purposes, I am simply including the required files of the billing information (which I am logged into successfully). I then print the output of the $_SESSION array, which is populated by the billing system (encoded code) and then exit:

Code for client/logincheck.php

```
    require("dbconnect.php");
    require("includes/functions.php");
    require("includes/clientareafunctions.php");

    print_r($_SESSION);
    die();
```

If I browse to that URL directly in a browser (client.domain.com/logincheck.php) - I get the following output:

```
    Array ( [calinkupdatecc] => 0 [calinkupdatesq] => 0 [uid] => 1 [upw] => a49de38fe12d325feb11bc9be1762482 [cainvorderby] => status [cainvsort] => DESC [cadomorderby] => domain [cadomsort] => ASC [caemailsorderby] => date [caemailssort] => DESC [caprodorderby] => product [caprodsort] => ASC )
```

This is what I would expect.

However, from the front end - the div only has an empty array appended:

```
    Array()
```

If the jQuery was working, it should be (at the moment, anyway) - that SESSION array, shouldn't it?

In case this is relevant - my php.ini file has the session.cookie_domain - .domain.com  setting in there.

Thanks for any help.

** EDIT **

I replaced the code in client/logincheck.php with:

```
    if ($_SESSION['uid']) {
        echo "Logged In";
    } else {
       echo "Not logged in";

   }
   die();
```

And now the bizarre thing is - I browse to the page directly, and I get 'Logged In' output to the screen. Fro the frontend, I get 'Not Logged in' echoed out.

So how can a direct visit to the URL show a valid session, but using GET to retrieve the page show something else?

Comment: I've never tried sending a php array to jquery. Are you sure jquery can understand it structurally? Maybe try encoding it in json? Here's an example of json if you think that might help. http://www.darian-brown.com/pass-a-php-array-to-javascript-as-json-using-ajax-and-json_encode/

Comment: Have you tried using FireBug to see if you are having a problem with your Javascript?

Comment: Maybe you just need `session_start()` before the `print_r`?

Comment: Hi guys - thanks - I'll add this same comment below. I've edited the post above showing replacing the output with simple text. The issue seems to be that the GET query isn't showing a session array set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know "The Right" answer per say, but what I would start by trying this:

1. Open up a webkit browser (Chrome, Safari, etc.)
2. Open up the developer tools so you can catch the AJAX request (under the "Network" tab)
3. Take a look at the "Request Headers"
4. Take a look at the "Response"

I suggest looking at the request headers because the `$.get` method tries to intelligently guess what the data type coming back is unless you fill out that param[1].  I'm not 100% sure this could have anything to do with it, but maybe something funky is going on behind the scenes if it thinks it's getting back a different data type.

I also suggested looking at the actual response headers so you can see what's *actually* coming back.  I was doing something similar on my backend and I was getting back an array of objects, so when I appended the response, it output `Array`.

Like I said, this is just a starting point, I'd need to see the code to better help you out.

[1] jQuery $.get documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Hiya - I've added an edit to the bottom of my question, to rule out the data complexity factor. See if that gives you any ideas?

Comment: The only thing I can say is to check your source control from 2 days ago and see what changed.  Your `session.cookie_params` is set up right to handle subdomains so that's definitely not it.  I would need to see the complete code, though, because it sounds like your session si getting overwritten.  Is your edit the ENTIRE piece of code in that file?  If not then it's something above that block.  Maybe check to see if things get handled differently for incoming XMLHttpRequests?